# Can the METHOD attribute in html and the POST variable in PHP be of different case?

Tags: php, html, post, case-sensitive

I know the method attribute in HTML form is case insensitive and can have 'post' or 'POST' in it. It is case insensitive.

But my query is, if attribute in HTML is

```
method="post"
```

then can we use

```
$variable=$_POST['variable']
```

in capturing the post in PHP ? Is the case difference ok ?

I mean, can I use $variable = $_post['variable'] or $variable = $_POST['variable'] in my PHP file irrespective of  method='post' or method='POST' in the HTML ?

Comment: variables in php are case sensative. `$_POST` is a (superglobal) variable. It will always have the same name.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation ..however, i have edited the question to be a bit more specific on my query

Comment: Thanks for the answer, Steve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your html, you can use `method="post"` or `method="POST"` it don't matter, but I recommend you to use `post`.

Concerning, `$_POST` variable :

> An associative array of variables passed to the current script via the
>   HTTP POST method when using application/x-www-form-urlencoded or
>   multipart/form-data as the HTTP Content-Type in the request.

**Since it's a variable name, it's case-sensitive.**

Then you can't use `$_post`. you have to use `$_POST`.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation ..however, i have edited the question to be a bit more specific on my query

Comment: Thanks for the answer :)

Answer (score 0):

The PHP variable `$_POST` will **not vary** depending on the case used in the HTML form `method` attribute. `$_POST` is a defined variable in PHP which will be populated with data from the HTTP request body. That's how the variable is defined and that's how it works. It's not like PHP is implicitly converting the form's `method` attribute into a variable. In fact, PHP has no idea what the form's `method` attribute is, since that information is not carried over to the server.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, deceze